# How to Hide Configurable Dropdown when Apply MAP is Set to "Yes"?

Tags: magento-enterprise, configurable-product, price, drop-downs

Our site is programmed to show "Call for Price" when Apply MAP is set to "Yes". This is not an issue with simple products but with configurables it still shows the dropdown. We would like to "Hide" the entire dropdown when Apply MAP is set to "Yes" for Configurables. How do you achieve this? I have been looking at these two files.

frontend/package/theme/template/catalog/product/price_msrp_item.phtml
frontend/package/theme/template/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml

*Note: Removing associated products is not a solution because doing so removes the Configurable Product from the Catalog.